# Unable to Compile Java Package

Tags: java, compilation

Whenever I try to compile a package with 2 files I get

```
javac InsertionSort/*.java
InsertionSort/Test_Driver.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        array = Insertion_Sort(array);
                ^
    symbol:   method Insertion_Sort(int[])
    location: class Test_Driver
```

I've Tried everything And I can't get it to work.

Comment: Clearly you haven't tried everything, otherwise it would work.  Now where (and how) is `Insertion_Sort` defined?

Comment: are you cmpiling InsertionSort but the class name is Insertion_Sort????

Comment: Insertion_Sort is another class.  InsertionSort is the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it like a method, and thus it's looking for a method.  Because there's no method with that name, it fails.

If you mean to call a constructor, you forgot the word `new`.  If you intended to call another method in your `Insertion_Sort` class, you forgot to specify its name.